# How can I align an element of a struct?

Tags: c, struct, alignment

Is there any way to force an alignment of a particular element of a struct using a GNUism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [6.54.8 Structure-Packing Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)

> For compatibility with Microsoft
>   Windows compilers, GCC supports a set
>   of #pragma directives which change the
>   maximum alignment of members of
>   structures (other than zero-width
>   bitfields), unions, and classes
>   subsequently defined. The n value
>   below always is required to be a small
>   power of two and specifies the new
>   alignment in bytes.
>
> 1. `#pragma pack(n)` simply sets the new alignment.
> 2. `#pragma pack()` sets the alignment to the one that was in
>      effect when compilation started (see
>      also command line option
>      `-fpack-struct[=<n>]` see Code Gen Options).
> 3. `#pragma pack(push[,n])` pushes the current alignment setting on an
>      internal stack and then optionally
>      sets the new alignment.
> 4. `#pragma pack(pop)` restores the alignment setting to the one saved at
>      the top of the internal stack (and
>      removes that stack entry). Note that
>      `#pragma pack([n])` does not influence this internal stack; thus it is
>      possible to have `#pragma pack(push)`
>      followed by multiple `#pragma pack(n)`
>      instances and finalized by a single
>      `#pragma pack(pop)`.
>
> Some targets, e.g. i386 and powerpc,
>   support the `ms_struct` `#pragma` which
>   lays out a structure as the documented
>   `__attribute__ ((ms_struct))`.
>
> 1. `#pragma ms_struct on` turns on the layout for structures declared.
> 2. `#pragma ms_struct off` turns off the layout for structures declared.
> 3. `#pragma ms_struct reset` goes back to the default layout.

Answer (score 3):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

```
aligned (alignment)
This attribute specifies a minimum alignment (in bytes) for variables of the specified type. > For example, the declarations:
        struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
        typedef int more_aligned_int __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the attribute aligned on the structure:

```
__attribute__((__aligned__(8)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the things listed, you may also be interested in **attribute**((packed)) which attempts to lay out data without any padding -- essentially with alignment set to 1.
This is useful when discribing the layout of data in a file or network protocol where padding bytes should just go away.